# How did the RCA1802 'call' and 'return' instructions work?

Tags: rca-1802

The RCA 1802 processor was used in a number of systems such as the ELF and COMX-35, and also apparently in the US space program (with its hardened variant).

From memory, it had a rather unusual set of instructions for doing function calls and returns. Can anyone detail how this actually worked in practice?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The 1802 used a method known as SCRT, the standard call and return technique. The chip was actually endowed with a full complement of sixteen 16-bit general-purpose registers<sup>(a)</sup>, but no *dedicated* stack pointer or program counter. The SCRT was one method for doing calls using this limitation.

You could actually use *any* register as the program counter with the `SEP Rn` instruction (where `n` was a value `0..F` indicating which of the registers was to be used). This basically said to start using *that* register for the program counter, leaving whatever register was *previously* being used with its last contents (one byte beyond the `SEP` instruction that switched the program counter over).

So, by using some of those sixteen registers in a dedicated manner, you could easily "emulate" the more conventional instructions found on other processors.

Note that the details below are from rather distant memories, they may not be exact (in terms of what registers were used for what, for example), but they should give you the basic idea.

---

There was a "usual" program counter (`R3`), and the `R4` and `R5` registers were set respectively to the addresses of the SCRT `call` and `return` functions. `R2` was used as a stack pointer.

In order to *call* another function, you therefore encoded a `SEP R4` followed by the address that you wanted to call. This immediately started using `R4` as the program counter, leaving `R3` pointing at the memory containing the address that you were calling.

The SCRT `call` code running at `R4` would:

- store the return address (`R3`, to be adjusted on return to skip over the address) onto the stack (controlled by `R2`);
- load the address you wanted to call (pointed at by `R3`) *into* `R3`; then finally
- execute `SEP R3` to continue execution at that new address.

It would, of course, have to ensure `R4` was set back to the start of the SCRT `call` function and, from memory, this was done by placing the `SEP R3` instruction immediately *before* that function and then jumping to that as the final step. This would auto-magically leave `R4` set to the correct value for next time.

---

Similarly, a `SEP R5` (return) in your code would start running the `return` function which would:

- pull the return address off the stack at `R2`, into `R3`, and adjust it to skip over the address.
- do `SEP R3` (using the same jump trickery mentioned above to ensure `R5` once again pointed to the `return` function) to return to the original code.

---

So, in terms of implementation, the set-up was something like:

```
ScrtCallDone:
    sep r3
ScrtCall:
    ; code for doing reg/mem manipulations for call
    br ScrtCallDone

ScrtRetDone:
    sep r3
ScrtRet:
    ; code for doing reg/mem manipulations for ret
    br ScrtRetDone

macro fcall %address:
    sep    r4
    dw     address
endmacro

macro fret:
    sep    r5
endmacro
```

Then, in terms of what you would see in your code, it would be as simple as:

```
    fcall subfunc
    ; do other stuff then return

subfunc:
    ; do sub-function stuff
    fret
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> This rather massive (at the time) register bank was actually one of the big selling features of the chip, despite the fact you immediately lost a large chunk of them (SCRT, DMA and interrupts, from memory). Truly the triumph of marketing over reality :-)

Comment: Ha!  That's a beautiful hack. I designed a [processor](https://hackaday.io/project/159003-c61) earlier this year that has its PC in a general purpose register and copied the last PC into another register whenever that register is modified, but if I'd thought of doing it this way it would have saved the need to update the register file twice in a single cycle! Although a call+return on my system *is* two instructions shorter...

Comment: This description seems pretty similar to the IBM S/360 "Branch and link" and "Branch and link register" instructions, which used the same basic idea for subroutine calls. S/360 did have a program counter, but it didn't have a stack pointer, so the BAL or BALR instructions had to save the program counter in a *user-defined* location - either in another register, or in memory.

Comment: @alephzero, it *is* very similar. The admittedly minor stuff I did on the System z at IBM SW Labs actually reminded me of the 1802. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664744/what-is-the-direction-of-stack-growth-in-most-modern-systems/664779#664779 (the answer of mine that I sourced for this) for detail.

Comment: Would you really define a macro and then name it `ret`? `ret` is also a mnemonic for instruction 0x70 which is "return" and seems to do some kind of pop. http://www.ittybittycomputers.com/IttyBitty/ShortCor.htm

Comment: @Wilson, probably not, I haven't actually *used* my old COMX-35 for about 30 years so my memory won't be perfect :-) Adjusted to use different macro name.

Comment: The later 1804/1805/1806, and the "A" suffix versions of those, added actual stack-based call and return instruction. They used the formerly undefined/unusable 0x68 opcode as the prefix byte for a bunch of new two-byte instructions. However, these enhanced processors were mostly only seen in embedded systems, and not in many general-purpose computers. Part of the problem is that the "load mode" which allowed booting an 1802 from toggle switches or a keypad was removed in the enhanced processors.

Comment: While the fact that any register could be the program counter and stack pointer, it limited the portability of code because unless the other program you were working with used the same techniques, you'd have to rewrite it to use whatever scheme your own code used.  The SCRT was a convention and not universally used,

Comment: @EricSmith: I wonder how much hardware one would have to add to an 1804/1805/1806 system to allow a front-panel program load without needing a programmed ROM chip?  For example, if an access to any address in the bottom quarter of the address space would stall the CPU until a contact closure and then report the state of eight other contacts, I would think that could allow an initial program to be loaded by dragging a pegboard over the switches.

Comment: @supercat AFAICT it would take a LOT of additional circuitry to make the 1804/05/06 do the equivalent of LOAD mode. You can hold the CPU in reset, but it doesn't tristate the bus, so you'd need buffers, an address counter, and some control logic.

Comment: @EricSmith: If a fetch from a low address would wait for a contact closure and then read a byte, and RAM was available at e.g. address 0x8000-0x83FF, then storing a looping boot loader into RAM would require feeding about 20-30 bytes.  A bit of a nuisance if one doesn't have a mechanical means of automatically feeding the data, but I think the only electronics needed would be a 7474 to trigger the wait state, a 74373 to connect the switches (needed even with load mode), and a couple of quad-NAND chips for the address decoding (at least one of which would likely needed in any case).

Comment: @EricSmith: The big convenience factor with load mode is the ability to read back the code one has entered, but if one can input data from pegboards, punched strips, or other such means, one could write on such media a boot loader that's nicer than LOAD mode.

Comment: @EricSmith: What difficulties would you see with having a range of address space that would halt the CPU until a switch is pushed and then put the state of some switches onto the data bus?  Or alternatively, replace the '373 with a CD4094 shifter and use a 556 to make a circuit which would interpret a short pulse as shifting in a zero, a medium pulse as shifting in a one, and a long pulse as end-of-byte.  Add an audio-detector circuit and one could load programs directly from tape with no ROM required (perhaps have a switch to control whether the 556 timers operate at human or audio speeds).

Comment: @supercat You can bring /WAIT low to pause the CPU, but it still doesn't tristate the bus. There are any number of ways you could contrive to load code into RAM without using a ROM, but all of them are more complicated than just adding a ROM.

Comment: @EricSmith: If RAM starts at an address well above 0x0000 (e.g. address 0x8000), why would one need any special ability to tri-state the bus?  The only thing mapped at address 0x0000 would be either a 74373 or a CD4094.

Comment: I guess I don't understand how you're proposing to make that work.

Answer (score 4):

The RCA 1802 was a relatively strange beast in that it didn't *have* a dedicated program counter (or a dedicated stack pointer for that matter). Instead, it had the ability to select one of its 16-bit registers to act as the PC, and this could be changed at runtime with a simple instruction `SEP` (set program counter).

This scheme allowed for efficiencies where, if a function was *important* enough (and the code was simple enough), a register could be dedicated to it as follows:

```
fn_exit:
    sep r0          ; return to caller, r8 again points to fn.
fn:
    ; do stuff.
    lbr fn_exit     ; go to "return" section.

;   ----------

init_code:
    ldi r8, fn      ; set r8 to point to fn.

;   ----------

main_code:
    sep r8          ; call fn, leaving r0 set to next address.
```

The initialisation code sets `r8` to be the address of `fn`. Then, at some point after that, your can simply `sep r8` and the processor will magically start running `fn`. But there's a few caveats to that:

1. This is fine for calling *one* level down but doesn't really scale to general-purpose code where you need to call through many levels.
2. The function returns by branching to the code immediately *before* the start of the function. This trick ensures that, on exit, `r8` once again points to `fn`, since it's updated to the next address as part of instruction fetch.
3. The function has to know that `r0` is being used as the calling PC since that's how it does the return.
4. If `r8` changes to something else, you better set it back to `fn` before using this scheme again, or things are unlikely to end well :-)

---

So this is fine for very simple applications, as you may find in a dedicated-task system.

However, in order to scale up to an *arbitrary* number of function levels, a method called SCRT (standard call and return technique) was used. This technique dedicates a few registers for handling the call and return operations. For example, it may use:

- `r3` as the normal program counter;
- `r2` as the stack pointer;
- `r6` as a scratch register.
- `r4` dedicated to the call function address; and
- `r5` dedicated to the return function address.

Like `r8` and `fn` in the code above, those two final registers were initialised to the address of the SCRT call and return functions respectively. And, again, those functions were written such that these registers would be the same value after they had done their job.

To *define* a function, you simply wrote the code you wanted and ended it by activating the SCRT return function. I'm using that "activate" term to indicate a `sep` operation, so as to distinguish it from the higher level SCRT call. So something like this:

```
fn:
    ; do stuff.
    sep r5          ; scrt return.
```

---

To *call* a function, you needed to activate the SCRT call function but also encode the address of the function you wanted to call<sup>(1)</sup>:

```
    sep r4          ; scrt call
    defw fn         ;    with the address to call.
```

The functions referenced by `r4` and `r5` used the same trick as in the simple code described above (see `fn_exit`). They finished by branching to the code immediately before the function to ensure the register was once again set correctly. But the "meat" of each was adapted for the more general-purpose calling convention.

As per my earlier footnote<sup>(1)</sup>, this code uses utility macros, such as `scall` and `spush`, to make things simpler and not clog up the source with unnecessary repeating code. The SCRT call function would be something like:

```
scall_exit:
    sep r3

scall_fn:
    lda r3          ; get high byte of target to r6 high,
    phi r6          ;    incrementing r3.
    lda r3          ; same for low byte to r6 low,
    plo r6          ;    r3 now at return address.
    
    spush r3        ; push that return address.

    xfer r6 r3      ; prepare r3 to be target,
    lbr scall_exit  ;    and activate it.
```

In other words, it:

- saved the target address into scratch register;
- stored return address onto the stack;
- loaded scratch register into `r3`; then
- activated `r3` to effectively jump to the target address.

---

Returning would be the *opposite* actions, but rather simpler than the call operation:

- retrieve the return address from the stack into `r3`; and
- activate `r3` to effectively return to after the call.

This could be implemented as little more than:

```
sret_exit:
    sep r3

sret_fn:
    spop r3         ; prepare r3 to be return address,
    lbr sret_exit   ;    and activate it.
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> If you had a decent assembler, you could create macros to do the heavy lifting for you, as follows. I've also included some utility functions as well given the simplicity of the RCA 1802 instruction set:

```
macro scall %1      ; scall <address> [calls a function].
    sep r4
    dw %1
endmacro

macro sret          ; sret [returns from function].
    sep r5
endmacro

macro spush %1      ; spush rN [pushes a register].
    ghi %1          ; store each byte, decrementing sp.
    stxd
    glo %1
    stxd            ; sp always points at first free location.
endmacro

macro spop %1       ; spop rN [pops a register].
    irx             ; increment sp to skip free location.
    ldxa            ; get/store low byte, increment sp.
    plo %1
    ldx             ; get/store high byte, no increment.
    phi %1
endmacro

macro xfer %1 %2    ; xfer rX rY [transfers register rX to rY].
    ghi %1          ; transfer both bytes.
    phi %2
    glo %2
    plo r3
endmacro
```

Comment: That would be great for coroutines and continuations as well.

Comment: @Dan, yes, I vaguely recall an embedded system where there were two tasks and each simply used its own register. Task 1 used (for example) R3 and switched with `sep r4`, while task 2 used R4 and switched with `sep r3` (both with the trick of switching immediately before the code that was entry point. Could handle more than two of course but limited by registers. At some point SCRT becomes necessary.